# File under views not accessible in grails

Tags: javascript, grails, uri

We need to use a Javascript license file for a commercial Javascript library that we are using in our Grails application. The license needs to be placed in same folder as view, since it doesn't support relative paths specification for the license file. 
Our view is located in grails-app/view/video. 
When we put the license file in the folder we can't access it in browser like.. app-url/video/license.txt
Whereas when we place it in some other folder, say: "../assets/libray/license.txt" then we are able to access it through browser using URL app-url/assets/library/license.txt

Since relative paths are not supported by JS library, we're unable to use this technique.

Is there any way to access file located under views folder through URL ? or is there any specific configuration setting required to get this done ?
Any suggestion and comments will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you configure your environment and map static files there you have no other option then setup your `UrlMapping.groovy` and serve the static contents from there. In your `UrlMappings.groovy` add:

```
"video/license.txt"(controller: 'view', action: 'license')
```

and in the `view` controller:

```
def license () {
   def file = new File('/license.txt') // change this!
   response.setContentType("text/plain")
   response.outputStream << file.newInputStream() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Our goal is not to show the file as a new view, but use it in Javascript like:
initializeLicenseManager("586-314-458-491-813-779-273-371-662-173-273.txt");

Comment: So change the `UrlMapping` to "video/586-314-458-491-813-779-273-371-662-173-273.txt"(controller: 'view', action: 'license') or use the pattern matching if the file is dynamic.

Comment: Our basic purpose is to exclude particular action and use this license file instead

Comment: In that case use `exclude` like: class UrlMappings { static excludes = [....] ... }